# "change subscription", "manage subscription", "pricing" how to name the button that leads to the pricing page?

Tags: buttons, copywriting, pricing

**Сontext:**

It's a web app. In your profile settings, there's a **payments tab**, where you can see your whole **payment history neatly organized in a table**.

**Above the table, there's a button.**

When you click the button you get redirected to the pricing page where you can **downgrade/upgrade**.

**Question:**

**How should I name that button?**

I need a word or phrase that would mean "**see all plans and upgrade or downgrade**"

**"change subscription", "manage subscription", "pricing", or maybe some other suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

**I would say "Change Plan" or "Change Subscription".**

Since they are already in the Payments Tab, they won't be surprised to see pricing information if they click on a button that says "Change Plan" or "Change Subscription" button. These buttons will indicate the part of the app they need to go to in order to adjust their subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Is it one choice? Then "change". But arguably, then is should not even be a page but just 1 button/dropdown.

Is it a bunch of different choices, i.e. name/address/subscriptionplan/paymentmethod, then manage.